# How do I update a win32 dialogItem outside of the callback?

Tags: winapi

I've got a Dialog that is created this way:

```
CreateDialog(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_NETWORKCONFIG),
        hWnd, Network);
```

The dialog has some buttons, text boxes, etc.... everything works fine.
I can update the text in the text boxes based on input from outside the callback (in this case, the number of packets read), and send information from the callback back to the main loop.

It all works, except....

The dialog is only updated when a callback happens, which requires me to move the mouse around. So, I see the number of packets constantly updating if I move the mouse around, but not if I hold still. If I hold still, then move, the number jumps by the appropriate amount.

So, how can I either:

1. Force the callback to occur regardless of whether there is mouse movement
2. Update the dialog box items (text boxes) from the main loop of the program?

I've tried to do item 2, but the HWND I get back is always bad.

I need a function that is callable from the main loop that says:

```
HWND h(GetDialogHandle(IDD_NETWORKCONFIG); // this is made up function, tried many
Static_SetText(GetDlgItem( h, IDC_EDIT3 ), (LPSTR)std::to_string(long long(NC->mNumSent)).c_str() );
```

Thanks.

Comment: The return value of `CreateDialog` is the dialog's window handle.  Can't you use that in place of `h` in your sample code?

Comment: Good idea. That almost worked. There are three text boxes, ID_EDIT3, ID_EDIT4, ID_EDIT5. ID_EDIT3 now updates like a champ. The exact same Static_SetText line, using EDIT4 and 5, doesn't work. It only updates if I click in those text boxes. Very odd. There are no differences between the resources except the name. Any ideas? Debugger shows that the data going to it is non-zero.

Comment: Never mind above..... cleaned up code. It works. Thanks!